# Symfony 4 access_control not working by roles

Tags: php, symfony

I try to set access level on my routes and i wrote this simple 
**security.yaml**

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
encoders:
    App\Entity\User: bcrypt

providers:
    db_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: mobile
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: verify_token_page
            check_path: verify_token_page
            default_target_path: panel_index

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
     - { path: ^/panel, roles: ROLE_SERVICE_MAN }
```

Problem is , when i try to access *localhost:8000/panel* , i get **AccessDeniedHttpException**

Here is my user role dump

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "ROLE_SERVICE_MAN"
]
```

And i also tried to use not roles but role or wrap ROLE_SERVICE_MAN with brackets

Here is my PanelController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Car;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\CarType;
use App\Repository\CarRepository;
use App\Repository\RequestRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

/**
 * @Route("/panel")
 */
class PanelController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @Route("/",name="panel_index")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('panel/index.html.twig');
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to use not `roles` but `role` or wrap `ROLE_SERVICE_MAN` with brackets (to make an array)?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov yes

Comment: Also check that you successfully injected `security.yaml` into your service container by importing it in the main config file for your environment

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov checked .

Comment: Post here code from your controller

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov added

Comment: Your `.yml` is not correct. Everything under `security:` must be indented and `roles` key under `access_control` must be an array or replaced with `role:` as @MichaelSivolobov mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Domagoj i tried that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK ,
Point 1 : i found the problem never try to change user role directly from your database  because that set once when you login in cache or cookie or etc ... (i dont know where exactly)
when you change you should re login or add another user to set new roles .

Point 2 : check key Roles ( and do not add Role [my mistake]) in your entity .