# Symfony 4 : access_control doesn't work after deleting a user's role

Tags: symfony, security, roles

I'm try to deny access to a user by deleting his role (`ROLE_MEMBER`), here my `access_control` in security.yaml file :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    #- { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/admin/users, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/%locale%/.+/(edit|delete|add|request|accept|deny), roles: ROLE_MEMBER }
```

It appears that it doesn't work. User still have access to, for example, http://localhost:8000/fr/blog/edit/13 and when I display roles like this in a template :

```
{% for role in app.user.roles %}
    {{ role }}
{% endfor %}
```

I don't get `ROLE_MEMBER` so it is well deleted.
The fact is that I have to login again to see `access_control` work.

I would like to know where is stored the user (as mentionned in that [question (Point 1 of answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278440/symfony-4-access-control-not-working-by-roles)) and how to make effect without relogin ?

Comment: If you’re deleting the user, the URL should return a 404 or I missed something

Comment: I'm not deleting the user but his role (`ROLE_MEMBER`)